# PDO_MYSQL: general error 2014

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm migrating from plain mysql_* to PDO (yeah, I know it's 2012 on the calendar).
I'm writing a simple wrapper class to have an opportunity to do things like
    $f=$db->FetchAll("SELECT * FROM...")
on my website.
Here's what I'm doing:

```
    public function Query($q, $errmessage="", $params=array()) {
    try {
    $stmt=$this->connect->prepare($q);
    if (is_array($params) && count($params)>0) {
    $stmt->execute($params);
    } else {
    $stmt->execute();
    }
    return $stmt;
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
    die($errmessage.": ".$e->GetMessage());
    }
    }

   public function Fetch($q, $arraylist=0) {
    if (!is_object($q)) { // Assuming it's a raw query
    $stmt=$this->Query($q, "Unable to process the query for fetching");
    } else $result=$q;
    $f=$stmt->Fetch();
    return $f;
}
```

And this throws a "general error 2014" exception.
Any help appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Are you able to pin-point the line ?
Can you provide the whole class ( it's probably because one of the attribute does not contain what you expect )

Comment: Here it is: [PasteBin](http://pastebin.com/rAUyCLna). Thanks in advance!

Comment: It probably doesn't solve your problem, but instead of calling your own query function that prepare a query that never have any variables, why don't you just use http://php.net/manual/fr/pdo.query.php ? It will be a little faster.

Comment: I've located the error. It's here: `PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND=>"SET NAMES utf8; SET CHARACTER_SET_DATABASE='utf8'; SET TIME_ZONE='Europe/Kiev'"`. *These* multiple queries are the cause of this error. What could you suggest instead? I absolutely need both UTF-8 character set and Europe/Kiev timezone. I would set it per-server but it's a shared hosting. Thanks in advance!

Comment: well, just 2 manual queries... ;) I don't believe you *have* to send them at the precise moment of the connection, try sending them as soon as the connection is established. At least that's what I've always done, so far without problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`2014` isn't a year, it's an error code. Try [googling the error](https://www.google.ca/search?q=pdo%20%22general%20error%202014%22) next time.

> $pdo->query("INSERT INTO `test` (some) VALUES ('1111111111111111'),
>   ('1111111111111'); -- I AM AN SQL COMMENT, REMOVING ME WILL SOLVE THIS
>   PROBLEM");
>
> Due to the ";" this is a multi-statement, executing two queries while
>   the second is only a comment. The second "result" can be accessed
>   using PDOStatement->nextRowset. [[source]](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=47504)

or:

> After spending hours trying to track down why we were getting this
>   error on a new server, after the same code ran fine on other servers,
>   we found the problem to be an old MySQL *client* library running on
>   our web server, and a latest-version MySQL *server* running on the
>   database server's box. [[source]](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php)

Comment: I'm aware of this multi-query issue. However the only place where there are multiple statements is this option: `PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND=>"SET NAMES utf8; SET CHARACTER_SET_DATABASE='utf8'; SET TIME_ZONE='Europe/Kiev'"`.

Comment: Updated the answer. MySQL client library was the only other issue I saw in my googlings of this error.

Comment: Don't be rude with him; He never said that he thought 2014 was a year, he sais that it was about time to migrate to PDO.

Comment: and yes, I was right. This option is the stumbling block. But what if I absolutely need UTF-8 charset and Europe/Kiev timezone? No way to set it per-server, it's a shared host. Thanks for any help.